# Is it a normal behaviour for a react native app?

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native app which doesn't work without `npm start running`. When I try to start it without USB connection, I have an error message:

> Unfortunately AppName has stopped working

I am working on android.

Does the problem go away when the app is deployed?

Thanks

Comment: It is a generic error message telling that there is something wrong in your code.

Comment: You won't need USB connection in deployed versions. Developing version is different than Production one.

Comment: If there is something wrong in my code, why it's working fine with 'npm start' ? And should I follow this documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html; to test the production version ? Or can I do the same with another way ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes It Is Normal Behavior As NodeJS Update the UI and implement the Code there 
is Need to Start **NPM** to make nodeJS work in ReactNative to work with Android

Comment: You might need to answer the actual question. as the headline is misleading

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll not accept it because, like @DineshPrajapati said, my headline is misleading and I am looking for a solution more than an answer to the headline. Sorry.

Comment: until you are working with reactnative you should keep your cmd on running background on which you started NPM

close CMD after you completed your project work for a day